# ComboBox selected item in windows 8.1 or windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

i have xaml like this :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbProvince1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="674,481,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="236" TabIndex="10">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Alberta"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="British Columbia"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Manitoba"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="New Brunswick"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Newfoundland and Labrador"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Nova Scotia"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Ontario"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Prince Edward Island"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Quebec"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Saskatchewan"/>
        </ComboBox>
```

when i do access the the selectedItem to C# i am not able to get the string value i wrote as content

var value = cbProvince1.SelectedItem;

i am not able to get value in c# .

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to reference the [`Content`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentcontrol.content) property, not the control itself. However, as `SelectedItem` return an object, yo uneed to cast it to a `ComboBoxItem`:

```
string content = ((ComboBoxItem)cbProvince1.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

Comment: there is no SelectedItem.Content in windows 8.1

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making your items `ComboBoxItem` and then casting its content you can set it to array of `string` and then `SelectedItem` will be of `string` type. This will also work for `Int32`, `Double` and other system types.

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="cbProvince1" SelectedIndex="1" ...>
    <sys:String>Alberta</sys:String>
    <sys:String>British Columbia</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Manitoba</sys:String>
    <sys:String>New Brunswick</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Newfoundland and Labrador</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Nova Scotia</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Ontario</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Prince Edward Island</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Quebec</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Saskatchewan</sys:String>
</ComboBox>
```

you'll need to define `sys` namespace

> xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

Comment: how about to make one item as selected : IsSelected="True"/>

Comment: OK, i will try this one

Comment: You can use `SelectedIndex` and also check my updated answer as I think Windows Phone does not support `x:Array`